# How to create a view in PostgreSQL with where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view

I am trying to create a view in Postgres

1. I have 3-4 time stamps in each closing_date where I need to select only the latest time stamp of each day
2. And also I have to restrict the closing_date to only 30 days (shown in SQL query below)

Below is the query from SQL data which I had created

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.CashBreaks_30Days_View as
SELECT Closing_date,Bo,Desk,Breaks_Staus,Owner,status,Team,
SLA,Age_Bucket_EntryDate,Age_Bucket_ValueDate,Age_EntryDate,Age_ValueDate,
[Type_(2)]
FROM Master_Data_CashBreaks
WHERE Closing_date >= cast(getdate()-37 as date);
```

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is intended for Oracle only (and to support migrations **to** Oracle). It's not a general DBMS independent tool that can be used for other products (and surely not easily for Postgres). If you are really using Oracle's SQL Developer I strongly suggest you look for a different [SQL GUI client](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients)

Comment: I suggest you create a new question for the "latest time stamp of each day" as that will require more information that this question contains

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, something like this *might* return result you want:

```
create or replace view cash_breaks_30days_view
as
select a.list_of_columns
from master_data_cashbreaks a
where a.closing_date >= trunc(sysdate) - 30             --> the last 30 days
  and a.closing_date = (select max(b.closing_date)      --> subquery is used to return
                        from master_data_cashbreaks b   --  the last timestamp per date
                        where b.id = a.id
                          and trunc(b.closing_date) = trunc(a.closing_date)
                       )
```

Comment: Hi i am getting below error "Error report -
ERROR: column "sysdate" does not exist
  Position: 435"

Comment: SYSDATE is a function, it is not a column, and it *exists* in every Oracle database, available to all users. Error you specify doesn't look like Oracle message. Are you **sure** you use Oracle?

Comment: Hi i am trying to create view in Oracle sql Developer.

Comment: That is a **tool**. I asked about **database**.

Comment: I don't know whether you're wrong or not, but - you should **know** which database you use. If it is PostreSQL, then I suggest you fix tags - remove Oracle and add PostgreSQL. Because, the way it is now, people who speak Oracle are answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes in your code:

1. `[Type_(2)]` - Not a valid SQL
2. `getdate()` - There is no such function available in Oracle. you should use the `trunc(SYSDATE)` instead.
3. `getdate()-37` - Why -37, when you want the last 30 days data. It should be 30.

Your query should look like this in oracle:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.CashBreaks_30Days_View as
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT Closing_date,Bo,Desk,Breaks_Staus,Owner,status,Team,
          SLA,Age_Bucket_EntryDate,Age_Bucket_ValueDate,Age_EntryDate,Age_ValueDate,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Closing_date ORDER BY Closing_date DESC) AS RN
     FROM Master_Data_CashBreaks
    WHERE Closing_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30)
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Tejash, i had given SQL query as an example does your above corrected query satisfies my time stamps on closing date issue

Comment: Hi Tejash Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE VIEW cashbreaks_30days_view_latesttime as
SELECT closing_date,age_entrydate,age_valuedate,age_bucket_entrydate,age_bucket_valuedate,owner,team,currency_code,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Closing_date ORDER BY Closing_date DESC) AS RN
     FROM Master_Data_CashBreaks
    WHERE Closing_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
WHERE RN = 1
Error report -
ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"
  Position: 541

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL contains a lot of errors

1. square brackets are invalid in SQL identifiers, if you have such a column you need to use double quotes. It's unclear to me if your column is named `"[Type_(2)]"` or maybe just `"Type_(2)"
2. There is no getdate() in SQL or in Postgres. Use `current_date` instead

So fixing all those error, your statement should look like this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.CashBreaks_30Days_View 
as
SELECT Closing_date, Bo, Desk, Breaks_Staus, Owner, status,
       Team, SLA, Age_Bucket_EntryDate, 
       Age_Bucket_ValueDate, Age_EntryDate, Age_ValueDate,
       "[Type_(2)]" -- or maybe only "Type_(2)"
FROM Master_Data_CashBreaks
WHERE Closing_date >= current_cate - 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

i am able to create with the below

create or replace view cashbreaks_30days_view_latesttime
as
select a. Column details

from master_data a
where a. Closing_date >= NOW() - interval '40 days'
  and a.closing_date = (select max(b.closing_date)
                        from master_data b
                        where date(b.closing_date) = date(a.closing_date));